# Serving an angular dist folder with go

Tags: angular, go

I'm simply trying to serve an angular application's dist folder using go. I tried an approach which worked well for me with react. e.g.

```
spa := http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("path/to/dist")))
// m is a gorilla mux router.
m.PathPrefix("/").Handler(spa)
```

However when I navigate to the port I'm serving on I receive a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using relative paths you have to be extra cautious about the working directory of your application. Try printing the value returned by [`os.Getwd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd) and see if it makes sense when combined with "path/to/dist".

Also, since `http.FileServer` checks if path starts with `/`, and if it doesn't it [adds it back](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?#L710), using `http.StripPrefix` with "/" is not needed.

Comment: That was correct, all relative paths are from my main function for some reason... Any way to work around this? Will I have to move things around for production?

Comment: You can provide whatever path you want to FileServer. If you don't know the path upfront, you could make your Go application to accept a command line argument that would be the absolute path, and just pass it to the FileServer. Can you give more context to what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a sqlite db file, a text file and a dist folder for an angular app all located in an assets folder in the root directory. It would be find if I just copied the asset folder into the same folder as the binary, however I want the paths to work in development and production.

Comment: I see, so your working directory is being set to where your go binary is stored. In that case I would go with the command line argument approach. In your go application, get the first argument passed to it ([look here](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments)) and pass it to FileServer. Then when you run your go application, pass the **absolute** path to your `dist` folder as the first command line argument. This will work everywhere, just pass different path in development and production.